# Testing Starknet Cairo contract function with address

Tags: python, starknet, cairo-lang

I built a module with Cairo language and I would like to unit test it. The contract is pretty simple : it manages a list of authorized addresses and provide some "modifier" functions to help.

I have taken the sample unit testing code from the documentation but nothing is referring about sending an account address to a function with python.

How should I proceed ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can spoof an account by providing the caller address to the invoke function like this:

```py
await contract.function(
    arg1=felt,
    arg2=felt2,
).invoke(caller_address=private_to_stark_key(123))
```

If you want a more detailed example of how the python unit testing framework works you can check these 2 links

https://github.com/starknet-edu/basecamp/blob/main/camp_4/buidl/tests/test_contract.py
https://github.com/starknet-edu/starknet-debug/tree/master/python